# Using Location State in Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a React project that requires the app URL to be fully-declared, static and immutable, so just:

`https://exampleurl.com/path/to/app/index.html`

..but none of the following:

`https://exampleurl.com/path/to/app/`

`https://exampleurl.com/path/to/app/index.html?query=value`

`https://exampleurl.com/path/to/app/subdir/index.html`

So, the project uses `state` and `withRouter` to provide basic app navigation.  The responsible component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import RenderNav from './RenderNav';
import Cohort from '../view/Cohort';
import Holdings from '../view/Holdings';
import Policy from '../view/Policy';
import Search from '../view/Search';
import Start from '../view/Start';
import Training from '../view/Training';
import WatchList from '../view/WatchList';

class RenderDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.props.location.state || { activeDisplay: 'start' };
    this.props.history.replace(this.props.location.pathname, this.state);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.setState(this.props.location.state);
    }
  }

  setDisplay() {
    let displayMode = [];
    let d = this.state.activeDisplay;

    switch(d) {
      case 'start': displayMode = [
        <Start key={`display-${d}`} />
      ]; break;

      // ...and so on - activeDisplay determines displayMode (and so screen contents)

      default: displayMode = [<div>Error</div>]; break;
    }; return displayMode;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.setDisplay()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(RenderDisplay);
```

The `location.state` object is set by the `<Link />` component:

```
<Link to={{ state: {activeDisplay: 'start'} }}>
  <button type="button">Home</button>
</Link>
```

The result is normal browser navigation throughout the app while the URL remains unchanged.

**My question is:** how can the class-based `RenderDisplay` component above be converted to a functional component (using hooks)?

I've tried several permutations of `useEffect`, `useState`, and `useLocation`, but I clearly don't understand hooks well enough to reproduce the behavior of the class-based component above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So,some steps that we always need to do:

1. No need of HOCs, specifically `withRouter`. We can use the `useHistory` hook instead.
2. All initialization either from the constructor or from `componentDidMount` can be done either directly in state, or in an `useEffect` that only runs once (empty dependency array).
3. All updates to state, specifically from `componentDidUpdate` can be done in an `useEffect` that depends on your state variable. In your specific case, you need the previous `prop` as well. In these situations, we can create a custom hook and use it. In my case, it will be `usePrev`.
4. All cleanup tasks, specifically from `componentWillUnmount` can be covered in an `useEffect` that returns the cleanup action.

Keeping these things in mind, these are probably the changes that need to be done:

Note: During this, I realized you are trying to render an array. I modified it to render a single element, you can update it otherwise.

```js
import {useRef} from "react";

export const usePrev = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
}
```

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useHistory, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import RenderNav from './RenderNav';
import Cohort from '../view/Cohort';
import Holdings from '../view/Holdings';
import Policy from '../view/Policy';
import Search from '../view/Search';
import Start from '../view/Start';
import Training from '../view/Training';
import WatchList from '../view/WatchList';
import usePrev from './usePrev';

const RenderDisplay = (props) => {

  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const prevLocation = usePrev(location);  

  const [componentState, setComponentState] = useState(location.state || { activeDisplay: 'start' });

  useEffect(() => {
    history.replace(location.pathname, componentState);
  }, [location.pathname, history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.state.activeDisplay !== prevLocation.state.activeDisplay) {
        setComponentState(location.state);
    }
  }, [location]);

  setDisplay() {
    let displayMode;
    let d = componentState.activeDisplay;

    switch(d) {
      case 'start': displayMode = <Start key={`display-${d}`} />; 
      break;

      // ...and so on - activeDisplay determines displayMode (and so screen contents)

      default: displayMode = <div>Error</div>; break;
    }; 
    return displayMode;
  }

  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {setDisplay()}
    </div>
  );
  
}

export default RenderDisplay;
```

Comment: I was able to implement this refactor with two changes to usePrev: 1) include the required useEffect; and 2) passing 'value' to useRef when initializing const ref.  The functional component is now running in production build.  Thanks!

Comment: I also had to add an additional useEffect to set the state property on the location object (which initializes as undefined).

Comment: Great! Glad you could finish up the solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? You can convert your class component to function this way.
Let me know if this helps.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function RenderDisplay() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [state, setState] = useState(
        location.state || { activeDisplay: "start" }
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        history.replace(location.pathname, state);
    }, [history, location, state]);

    const setDisplay = () => {
        let displayMode = [];
        const d = state.activeDisplay;

        switch (d) {
            case "start":
                displayMode = [<Start key={`display-${d}`} />];
                break;

            // ...and so on - activeDisplay determines displayMode (and so screen contents)

            default:
                displayMode = [<div>Error</div>];
                break;
        }
        return displayMode;
    };

    return <div className="container">{setDisplay()}</div>;
}

export default RenderDisplay;
```

Also for your this block of code,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.setState(this.props.location.state);
    }
  }
```

We need to handle in another `useEffect` hook.